# Expand a list view when clicked on an element of it

Tags: android, listview, expand

I am beginner in the android development, can any one tell me how to expand a list when I click on an element of it say an image icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it for me, due to privacy I can't write the whole code here

```
            TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);                
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
            if (desc.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
               icon.getLayoutParams().height = heightIcon;
               desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
               icon.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
               desc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Now when I click the icon, the text view placed below to it, becomes visible and thus has solved the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) and [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example code snippet to do it : [ExpandableList1.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)

You can even find it in your Android SDK folder

```
Drive:***\***\Android-sdk\samples\android-<apilevel>\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view\ExpandableList1.java
```